# Angular input disabled

Tags: angular, typescript

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knhkqu-grpmd5?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.ts

```
    <form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label></mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" [disabled]="filterValue" />

    <mat-label *ngIf="filterValue">Search</mat-label>
    <mat-label *ngIf="!filterValue"> No Search</mat-label>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="filter()">Basic</button>
</form>

     
    
      filterValue: boolean = false;
      filter() {
        this.filterValue = !this.filterValue;
      }
```

Main problem in my app is now that IF user will write something to searbbox filter is working but If I click button input is disabled (this is okey) and input is empty (this is okey) but If user will click second time button for enable **I want see date before [disabled] input** How save value in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example has a typo in line nr. 9:

```
<button mat-raised-button (ckick)="filter()">Basic</button>
```

Try `(click)` and not `(ckick)`

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="filter()">Basic</button>
```

Comment: thanks . In my app I have such problem that if input is enable I see "Search" and I will write inforamtions and   I will press button I see "No search" but after second click I want see date before lcick is this possible?